# Does the sum of two random variables that converge in distribution also converge in distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are defined on the same probability space, that $X_n$ converge in distribution to $X$ and that $Y_n$ converge in distribution to $Y$. I'm trying to find an illustrative example showing that $X_n+Y_n$ need not converge in distribution to $X+Y$. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Certainly $X_n$ and $Y_n$ cannot be independent...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X_n\sim\mathsf U[-1,1]$. Then $X_n$ converges in distribution to $X$ where $X\sim\mathsf U[-1,1]$ and also $X_n$ converges in distribution to $-X$ (since $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution). But $X_n+X_n$ does not converge in distribution to $X+(-X)=0$.